# Creating a div in Jquery and passing it through object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, liquid

Currently I'm able to pass just text to the ajax-cart-template but when I try to pass a element that I create it returns [object Object].

This is my code in ajax-cart.js. Now the hiddenProductText does get passed through. Just not the element I created.

```
    var hiddenProductText = "Add $99+ to Your Cart to get a Free Gift",
        bleh = $("#hiddenFree"),
        blehbleh = $("<div>", {id: "hiddenFreeTwo"});
    if(cart.total_price >= 9900){
      hiddenProductText = "Grab this Storage Box for Free!";
      var blehbleh2 = bleh.append(blehbleh);
      console.log(blehbleh2);
    }

    data = {
      items: items,
      note: cart.note,
      totalPrice: Shopify.formatMoney(cart.total_price, settings.moneyFormat),
      hidden_Product_Text: hiddenProductText,
      free_Product_Gift: blehbleh2
    }
```

And I pass my data to ajax-cart-template.

```
    <div class="ajaxcart__footer">
        <div class="grid--full">
         <span style="width:100%;color:#e75300;">{{hidden_Product_Text}}</span>
         <div id="hiddenFree">
           {{free_Product_Gift}}
         </div>
          <div class="grid__item two-thirds">
            <p>{% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.subtotal' | t }}{% raw %}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="grid__item one-third text-right">
            <p>{{{totalPrice}}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="text-center">{% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.shipping_at_checkout' | t }}{% raw %}</p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn1 btnBlock btnGreen cart__checkout" name="checkout" style="display:{{checkout_button_display}};" >
        <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
          {% endraw %}{{ 'cart.general.checkout' | t }}{% raw %}
        <div id="checkoutButtonOverlay"></div>
        </button>
        {% endraw %}{% if additional_checkout_buttons %}
          <div class="additional_checkout_buttons" style="display:{%raw %}{{checkout_button_display}}{% endraw %};" >{{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}</div>
        {% endif %}{% raw %}
        <span style='color:red;'>{{checkout_hidden_text}}</span>
      </div>
```

Comment: It may be due to the fact that you're passing an object/element that is not in the form of a string to be rendered.
Edit: (hit enter by accident) Are you certain the element blehbleh2 is actually being hit, and, it is an element to begin with, prior to the append line?

Comment: @fafafooey Ah you were right it the original var blehbleh wasn't an element so I changed variable to..
   blehbleh = $("<div>", {id: "hiddenFreeTwo"});
Console.logged it and it was an element. So I'd have change it to a string to pass it?

Comment: I would try it with the string to see what happens. Or, pass the element and then call innerHtml or something like that within the markup.

Comment: @fafafooey I tried and it wasn't working properly.. so I went with another quick solution from another recommendation haha. I read up on the mustache.js and realized I can just check to see if the hidden_Product_text was true or false with their syntax, since the ajax-cart-template is based off their js.
{{#if hidden_Product_Text}}
         <p class="ajaxcart__product-meta">{{hidden_Product_Text}}</p>
 {{/if}}